# Why Linear Algebra Done Right didn’t talk about similar matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m browsing through Axler’s Linear Algebra Done Right, to refresh my linear algebra. It seems adopted a relatively high standpoint view, ie treat matrix as linear mappings , so some proofs are much easier.

However, surprisingly, seems it didn’t talk about similar matrices , i.e. $B=P^{-1}AP$. Why is it not discussed?

Prof Axler definitely knows much more than the book. I’m just curious on the logic behind it,

E.g. if it’s due to there are some equivalent things already discussed in the book that I missed?

or it’s actually not so important or widely used in theory or applications?

or it’s a bit advanced that not in the scope of a book like LADR? In this case , after LADR, which book could be the next one to complet this part ?

Comment: You could ask the author: linear@axler.net

Comment: That still sounds like a question only the author could answer, as it was him who decided to present the content the way it is.

Comment: The only reason we care about similar matrices is because if $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space $V$ and $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to an ordered basis $\alpha$ and $B$ is the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to an ordered basis $B$ then $A$ and $B$ are similar. But if we focus our attention on $T$, which is the object we really care about, then I suppose discussing the relationship between $A$ and $B$ is unnecessary. The book isn't trying to be a comprehensive reference book, it's just showing how to develop the main theory elegantly and insightfully.

Comment: @JansthcirlU allow me rephrase it: if you are a professor prepare a LA course for undergraduate students , ie not an advanced course, based on LADR as the main textbook , would you supplement with additional materials or recommend to your class, on similar matrices topic?

Comment: @littleO if I’m not wrong, in abstract algebra we do discuss things like $N$ and $g^{-1}Ng$. Is it that in LA such case is trivial, only related to changing basis?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for the question about my book *Linear Algebra Done Right*. This book devotes major effort to the following question:

- If $T$ is a linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ to
  itself, then what conditions imply the existence of a basis of $V$ with respect to which $T$ has a nice matrix?

Here "nice matrix" might mean, for example, an upper-triangular matrix or a diagonal matrix or a Jordan matrix. Some examples of key theorems in *Linear Algebra Done Right* that help answer the question above are as follows:

- If $V$ is a complex vector space, then there exists a basis of $V$
  with respect to which $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix.
- If $V$ is a complex inner product space, then there exists an orthonormal basis of $V$
  with respect to which $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix.
- If $V$ is a real or complex inner product space and $T$ is self-adjoint, then there exists an orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to which $T$ has a diagonal matrix.
- If $V$ is a complex inner product space and $T$ is normal, then there exists an orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to which $T$ has a diagonal matrix.
- If $V$ is a complex vector space, then there exists a basis of $V$
  with respect to which $T$ has a Jordan matrix.

The theorems above all could have been stated in terms of similar matrices, but I preferred to keep the focus on linear maps and bases. The change of basis formula in terms of matrices does appear in *Linear Algebra Done Right* (see 10.7 in the third edition), although I do not use the "similarity" terminology.

In conclusion, the approach via similar matrices is equivalent to the approach via picking an appropriate basis, but I prefer the basis-centered approach for a second course in linear algebra that focuses on linear maps.

Comment: Thank you very much, LADR is one of my favourites.

Answer (score 2):

You say Axler treats matrices as linear maps to make proofs easier, but that's not the reason. After all, the book's not called *Linear Algebra Done Easily* . The reason is because linear algebra should be thought of in terms of linear maps rather than just vanilla matrices. A brief elucidation of this distinction explains why similar matrices are somewhat counterproductive in that respect.

It's easy to think of matrices as just rectangular arrays of numbers, on which we've defined multiplication by $(AB)v=A(Bv)$. In particular, if $\{e_i|i\in I\}$ is a basis, the linear map from $e_i$ to $\sum_jA_{ij}e_j$ can be represented with the matrix $A$, but a different matrix would be needed if we change basis. If $B=P^{-1}AP$, the replacement of each vector $u$ with $u=Pu^\prime$ rewrites $w=Av$ as $w^\prime=Bv^\prime$, thereby replacing $A$ with $B$.

It helps to distinguish [active and passive transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation). An active transformation moves a vector; a passive transformation changes the basis used to describe it. A specific linear map on a vector space (to either the same vector space or a different one) doesn't change under passive transformations, but an active transformation would talk about a completely different linear transformation.

Equivalence relations can be a conceptual double-edged sword. This can only be an educated guess (as @JansthcirlU pointed out), but I think Axler wanted to ensure readers don't reason "linear maps are matrices, some matrices are similar, therefore some linear maps are similar". They should instead reason, "similar matrices are different representations of the same linear map, but the same rectangular array of numbers represents different linear maps depending on the basis chosen".

Having said that, if I'd been in Axler's position I might have included a discussion of similarity that included such clarifications rather than avoid the topic altogether, **unless** doing so would be too unlike the style/theme of the rest of the book, with its focus on maps. (That may have been Axler's concern.)

Comment: I have never read LADR, but I have trouble imagining how such an approach could cleanly handle the fact that a matrix and its transpose are similar. Even stating that result abstractly is a small mess requiring a commutative square. While linear maps are obviously of extreme importance, the older I get the more I appreciate matrices as important objects in their own right.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson if both $A$ and $P$ are linear maps and $P$ inversible , is there theory/application on the relationship between $A$ and $B:=P^{-1}AP$?

Comment: @athos Yes, loads. Read any introduction to similar matrices. Then try diagonalization, say.